# Can anyone help me figure out why I keep getting an error with my lValue

Tags: c++

Can anyone help me figure out why I keep getting an error in my most inner looper the * gets highlighted saying that it must be a modifiable lValue.

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>


int main()
{


    //Part I 
     int DIM1 = 200; 
     int DIM2 = 400;
     int DIM3 = 200; 

     const int DIMM1 = 200;
     const int DIMM2 = 400;
     const int DIMM3 = 200;


     myTimer st;


    st.start();
    int a[DIMM1][DIMM2][DIMM3];
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < DIM2; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < DIM3; k++) {
                a[i][j][k] = i + j + k;
            }
        }
    }
    st.stop();
    st.time();
    cout << time << endl;


    st.start();
    //int *a;
    int * a = new int[DIM1*DIM2*DIM3];
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < DIM2; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < DIM3; k++)
                *(a + (i*DIM2*DIM3) + 
                    j * DIM3 + k) = i + j + k;

    st.stop();
    st.time();
    cout << time << endl;



    st.start();
    int a[DIMM1][DIMM2][DIMM3];
    for (int k = 0; k < DIM3; k++)
        for (int j = 0; j < DIM2; j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < DIM1; i++)
                a[i][j][k] = i + j + k;
    st.stop();
    st.time();
    cout << time << endl;


    st.start();
    //int *a;
    int * a = new int[DIM1*DIM2*DIM3];
    for (int k = 0; k < DIM3; k++)
        for (int j = 0; j < DIM2; j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < DIM1; i++)
                *(a + (i*DIM2*DIM3) +
                    j * DIM3 + k) = i + j + k;
    st.stop();
    st.time();
    cout << time << endl;



    return 0;
}
```

the errors are:

> ```
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   C2372   'a': redefinition; different types of indirection
> Error   C3863   array type 'int [400][200]' is not assignable
> Error   C2086   'int a[200][400][200]': redefinition
> Error   C2372   'a': redefinition; different types of indirection   
> Error   C3863   array type 'int [400][200]' is not assignable
> Error (active)  E0137   expression must be a modifiable lvalue
> ```

Comment: Other than declaring the variable `a` twice there is no problem with your code, please post the exact code that isn't compiling and the exact resulting error message(s). See [mcve].

Comment: Looks like it compiles fine to me: [ideone](https://ideone.com/HsDJqF)

Comment: I would use braces for the last loop...

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a typographical error. The compiler error makes it clear that you are attempting to redefine the variable `a` so I'm assuming you accidentally named it the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

When looking at c++ compiler errors you need to look at the first one first. The others may well be caused by the first.

In this case you are declaring lots of variables called `a` in the same scope. The compiler raises an error when you redeclare `a`:

> ```
> 'a': redefinition; different types of indirection
> ```

It then ignores this declaration and tries to continue compiling the rest of the file which results in the subsequent errors due to the variable types not being what you expect (the compiler is treating all instances of `a` in this file as an array).

You either need to use different names for each variable or enclose the variables in separate scopes. For example either of these are valid:

```
int a;
// do stuff with a
int b[10];
// do stuff with b
```

or:

```
{
    int a;
    // do stuff with a
}
// int a no longer exists
{
    int a[10];
    // do stuff with a
}
```